# If we rolled the die (6-sided) 1000 time, what is the range of times we'd expect to see a 1 rolled?

Tags: statistics, data-science

I got a question listed below about the confidence interval for **rolling a die 1000 times**. I'm assuming that the question is using Binomial Distribution but not sure if I'm correct. I guess in the solution, the probability 0.94 comes from 1-0.06. But I'm not sure if we need the probability in this interval, except it is only used for the Z-score, 1.88. Could I assume this question like this?

**Question:**
Assume that we are okay with **accidentally rejecting H0​ 6% of the time**, assuming H0​ is true.
If we rolled the die (6-sided) 1000 times, **what is the range of times we'd expect to see a 1 rolled**? (H0​ is the die is fair.)

**Answer:**
The interval is (144.50135805579743, 188.8319752775359), with probability = 0.94, mu = 166.67, sigma = 11.785113019775793

Answer (score 0):

We can treat this as a binomial distribution with a success chance *p* of 1/6 and number of trials *n* = 1000.

Mean value of such a distribution is *np*, and variance is *np(1-p)*. *sigma* (or std) is `sqrt(variance)`.

However, finding the interval is not so trivial since it requires an inverse CDF. The solution apparently uses normal approximation (*p* is low, *n* is high) with a Z-score table (like [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ersims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf)) thus range = *mu* +- 1.88 * *sigma*. Obviously, binomial is discrete, so there cannot be '145.5 times' of rolling 1. `scipy.stats.binom.ppf(0.97, 1000, 1/6)` and `scipy.stats.binom.ppf(0.03, 1000, 1/6)` yield a sane 145..189 range.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot! It's good to know an inverse CDF way to do this. Although I didn't know where the range formula, mu +- 1.88 * sigma, comes from, I found another formula for Normal Approximation of the Binomial Confidence Interval, p +- z(sub 1-α/2) * sqrt(p(1-p)/n), from this website https://sigmazone.com/binomial-confidence-intervals/. By multiplying the second formula 1000, this also get similar range.

Comment: Another website that can probably answer the "accidentally rejecting H0" term is stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/…. It states that "p*, the threshold below which we would reject the null hypothesis, is normally written as α, and is known as the false-positive rate. A "false-positive" error is the error of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true, and is also called a "Type-I" error. ."

Comment: Z-score of *x* is defined as *(x - mu) / sigma*. Z-score table matches the area under the normal curve (which is probability for conitinuous distributions) with a certain value - in other words, the probability of getting values that are over *1.88*sigma* and further from the *mean* for the normal distribution is 3%. Same for the negative side (two-sided test).

Comment: Now, by the definition of p-value (the probability to get the given or a more extreme result if the null hypothesis is true, not to be confused with *p* of the binomial distribution): if we rolled 1 e.g. 191 times, p-value would be lower than our alpha value of 3% and we'd reject our null hypothesis - the die is likely unfair. There's still a probability the die is fair, but it's lower than our threshold.

Comment: Thank you! The *1.88*sigma* clarifies the formula you mentioned. I already forgot the p-value and will review later.